# Is there a way to limit concurrent downloads in apt-get?

Tags: networking, apt, updates

I'm using:

```
apt-get dist-uprade
```

and it's about to drive me insane.

To make a long story short, I grew up in the country-side. We have electric fences to keep the bovine off the roads. 56k was actually 2k for us because of the static on the line. DSL speeds are anywhere from 1kb to 70kb/s. Apt-get is connecting to multiple servers concurrently on these swinging conditions. I feel it would be better to just limit apt-get to a single connection at a time instead of downloading two or three package files at once.

Comment: Thanks for this. I googled everything from concurrent downloads with apt-get to download speed  limits. . .